# Delete a cookie by its value

Tags: java, jsp, cookies

How do I delete a cookie by its value?

In my.jsp page I am setting the cookie

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy_HH:mm:ss:SSS").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
timeStamp = timeStamp + ":" + System.nanoTime();
String loc = "/u/poolla/workspace/FirstServlet/WebContent/WEB-INF/"+timeStamp;
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("path", loc);
```

Multiple users will have cookies with the same name but different loc values,
So, How do I get the cookie value in `servlet.java` and delete a particular loca value cookie??

Comment: For each user you will have different cookies stored in the server. Just because cookie name is same, it will not be same for every user. it's still unique tagged to `Session ID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Cookies`](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) are not same for each user. Generally cookies are tied to the client/user/browser which is accessing the JSP/application and each client can have a cookie value of its own.

When you delete a `cookie` you just delete it for the client which has made the request to your application. Rest of the clients will still have their own `cookie` without any effect in the value. Hence, you need not to worry about deleting a `cookie` may affect multiple users.

In order to delete a `cookie`, first get all the cookies from request and delete the cookie which has particular name/value.

```
public void delete(MyType instance) {
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            if (cookie.getName().equals("test")) {
                cookie.setValue(null);
                cookie.setMaxAge(0);
                cookie.setPath(theSamePathAsYouUsedBeforeIfAny);
                response.addCookie(cookie);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call getCookies() on the request and loop through them until you find the one you're looking for.

Answer (score -3):

here is a little simple example tha might help you

```
//declaring a cookie 
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, value);
//getting the cookie name 
String name = cookie.getName()
//getting the cookie value
String value= cookie.getValue();
```

Comment: This is not an answer to his question.